# How can I scrape the JSON file off this website?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I can't find any solutions for the problem I'm having.

I want to **scrape** the JSON file from https://www.armadarealestate.com/Inventory.aspx

When I go to the network and select the url where the JSON is being loaded from I just get sent to another HTML page, but the response section says that it contains the information about the properties which is what I need.

So how can I pull the JSON file from the website?

```
import json
import requests

resp = requests.get(url='https://buildout.com/plugins/3e0f3893dc334368bb1ee6274ad5fd7b546414e9/inventory?utf8=%E2%9C%93&page=-3&brandingId=&searchText=&q%5Bsale_or_lease_eq%5D=&q%5Bs%5D%5B%5D=&viewType=list&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=2&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=5&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=1&q%5Bcity_eq%5D=')

print(json.loads(resp.text))

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

In fact when I pull the request that belongs to the JSON file I instead get the response from scraping the url at 'https://buildout.com/plugins/3e0f3893dc334368bb1ee6274ad5fd7b546414e9/inventory?utf8=%E2%9C%93&page=0&brandingId=&searchText=&q%5Bsale_or_lease_eq%5D=&q%5Bs%5D%5B%5D=&viewType=list&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=2&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=5&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=1&q%5Bcity_eq%5D='
which is a html file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: 404, are you sure the url is the good one ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I think the url should work now.

Comment: I've tried adding headers={'content-type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'} to the request but still it gets the HTML.

Comment: Many REST APIs return different formats depending on which headers are informed; try to take a look at their API documentation (if available) or, if you have access to a working page, try to use the "Network" of the browser's debug tools to see what headers are being sent.

Comment: retry by adding a user agent to your request... maybe one of firefox, chrome... otherwise you send the requests-default and the server maybe doesn't like scrapers! Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633248/cant-parse-coin-gecko-page-from-today-with-beautifulsoup-because-of-cloudflare/68634188#68634188 and user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response object **"resp"** is not a valid JSON format. It is just a html content.
You can use [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to scrape the content from the html.

The reason you are not getting JSON object is due to the Javascript in the html. Python requests only download html document alone, if you want to render the Javascript use libs like selenium.

else, find the URL which loads the JSON via ajax and use requests to get JSON.

In your case, the tested code to scrape JSON:

```
import requests
url = "https://buildout.com/plugins/3e0f3893dc334368bb1ee6274ad5fd7b546414e9/inventory?utf8=%E2%9C%93&page=0&brandingId=&searchText=&q%5Bsale_or_lease_eq%5D=&q%5Bs%5D%5B%5D=&viewType=list&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=2&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=5&q%5Btype_eq_any%5D%5B%5D=1&q%5Bcity_eq%5D="
h = {'accept': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}  
r = requests.get(url, headers=h) 
print(r.json())

#prints the JSON data
```

Comment: But I don't want the HTML content, I want the JSON file. When I request the URL to the JSON file I get back HTML instead.

Comment: Are you entirely sure the URL is supposed to return JSON, at all? Not all sites use JSON.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but the response tab contains the JSON data but when I request the GET url it doesn't return the json data

Comment: I have done some test. It seems working. added the code above. Let me know if it works for you.